# How to start an activity from other activity but with specific intent - from OnNewIntent

Tags: android-activity, android-intent, nfc

Ok... so i guess the title is a bit confusing. so i will explain:
I have an NFC app which i handle a NDEF_DISCOVERED succesfuly in activity A. then a new activity is launched (B).
In this new activity (B) i want to be able to catch another tag and let activity A handle it as before, so i use OnNewIntent to get this intent of the tag and want to start activity A.
But if i call startActivity(myIntent) with the traditional myIntent = new Intent(this, A.class)   then activity A launced with this myIntent and i want the activity A to handle the tag intent that was 'caught' on activity B..

how can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add your tag intent in activity B as an extra to the traditional intent with [myintent.addExtra("tagkey", tagIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29).  Because Intent implements Parcelable, it will be added as a Parcelable extra.  Then in the onCreate() of activity A, put something like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("tagkey")) {
    setIntent(intent.getParcelableExtra("tagkey")
}
```

Replace the string "tagkey" with whatever is most relevant to your own code.  You can put a similar snippet in onNewIntent() as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the NDEF message type is specific enough such that only your Activity A will match it, you can set 'android:launchMode="singleTask"' in the activity section of your Android manifest for this Activity. Activity B will then be closed whenever you scan a new tag with the same type of NDEF message.